# What is the purpose of jquery.mobile.structure?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I downloaded the latest version of JQM and saw jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0-rc.1.css.

Q: What's that used for?  Do I need to include it in my project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the jQuery guys made a bit of an error on the jQuery Mobile 1.1rc1 page--

This link:  [Uncompressed structure without a theme: jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.css](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0-rc.1.css)

Should actually read:  [Uncompressed structure without a theme: jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0-rc.1.css](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0-rc.1.css)

If you wanted to create your own theme for jQuery Mobile, you would use that file as a basis.  Otherwise, if you want to just use the existing theme, you can ignore it (provided you use the regular css file, of course).

Comment: Thanks Mike!  I guess mine was a bit of an ignorant question.  I appreciate you covering for me by finding that typo in the docs.